# Transfer folder using SCP in airflow

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, airflow, scp

I want to transfer a folder from a Raspberry Pi using SCP command from SSHOperator in Apache Airflow, here are my task

```
transfer_files = SSHOperator(
    task_id='transfer_files',
    ssh_conn_id="ssh_raspi",
    command='sudo scp -r user@host:/home/pi/camera /home/sigurita/TASI120_data/RaspberryPi/',
    dag=dag,
)
```

I already make a ssh connection from the admin configuration for the password, make a public key so i can access ssh without typing password from the terminal, but the airflow keep ask me to put the password so the ssh is going error cause the time out.